# spliting google ng-autocomplete field value in angular and access that in node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Am having a google ng-autocomplete box in angular inside ng-repeat which have google places as their values , I need to split the value using the delimiter (,) and send it to the node js, I need to get that value also in node using req.body, is that possible please help me with a small code example, Thanks in Advance, Happy New Year

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far

Comment: @dreamweiver I don't have any idea on that could you please give me a idea so that I'll try and post the code here